# How to bounce to top with button on image with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make a hover effect to bounce an button to top. So i'm using CSS with hover and animating the margin-top. what happends that the image able to bounce to top but the button unable to bounce to top like images.

```css
img.hoverImages {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 3px;
  outline: 2px solid #DDD;
  border: #a1a1a1;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: margin 0.2s ease-out;
}
img.hoverImages:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<li>

  <div class="cont11">
    <img class="hoverImages" src="../images/wvm.jpg"/  ">
    <!-- <em class="game_wvm "></em>  -->

    <div class="game-name ">金刚狼</div>
    <div class="game-rollover clearfix "><a href="javascript:void(0); " class="real-play ">立刻开始</a>
    </div>
    <p class="game-progressive ">￥<span></span>
    </p>
  </div>
</li>
```

IMAGES HAS BEEN BOUNCE UP AS BELOW but as circle that button not bounce up : 
[image]

Comment: Your `<img>` has an extra quotation-mark.

Comment: by button you mean the `<a>` tag right ?

Comment: @Chris Hi i need to bounce up that div class of game-name

Comment: Can you have a look at this [codepen](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/KgzQJq). Check if this is what you want ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa Hi , i want something like http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ShapeHoverEffectSVG/# but i want to do it in css. as i try to use this tutorials but not working

Comment: @Morgan - In this example the image is not bouncing on hover, just the overlay div & the button becomes visible on hover. is this what you want ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa hmm , mthomp giving the right solution but i need once mouse move away , the circle need to move to the right instead of move back to bottom

Comment: ok. what are you considering as a 'circle' here ? The red outlined div ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa hi nik , you may refer to the images as upper , as i posted the image with circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling the image to transition not the div containing both the image and the circled area (the link). Add the transition (and hover) to the container instead, in this case that would be .cont11 then everything inside the container will move up.

Comment: hi mind show me the way how to do it ? im new on this . thanks you

Comment: Hi something like this https://jsfiddle.net/vL3hu7sL/ it looks a bit funny not having the images but the css is doing what you need. You need to move the transition to the .cont11 css then add whatever margin you want to the hover.

Comment: hi exactly what i want but i need the circle move to the right not moving to down after mouse move away. may i know how to do it

Comment: So you want the image and circle to both go up, then the image to go back down and the circle to go right when you stop hovering?

Comment: @MorganNg - something like [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vL3hu7sL/1/)

Comment: How about this https://jsfiddle.net/vL3hu7sL/2/ I used .cont11:hover .game-rollover to affect game-rollover when the cont11 is hovered over.

Comment: @mthomp Hi , not working either  , as the circle images not moving

Comment: Hi just alter this .cont11:hover .game-rollover to affect whatver div you want if game-rollover isn't the right one. Just .cont11:hover ."selector" and replace the selector with which element you want to move.

Answer (score 0):

change your style with this it should work

```
.cont11 {
  margin: 100px;
  padding: 3px;
  outline: 2px solid #DDD;
  border: #a1a1a1;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: margin 0.2s ease-out;
}
.cont11:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```